# How to clear all definitions/symbols declared in all sections with the given tag?

Tags: evaluation, cells, clear

Consider a list of chapters/sections etc. that have the same tag, say, "evaluation". Could you please tell me how to clear all the functions/symbols/definitions etc. that have been defined while evaluating this content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(* Step 1: Define a unique context *)
taggedContext = "EvaluationTag`";

(* Step 2: Clear all definitions in the tagged context *)
ClearAll[taggedContext <> "*"]

(* Alternatively, you can use Remove to remove symbols from the context *)
Remove["Global`" <> taggedContext <> "*"]
```

This code does the following:

- It defines `taggedContext` as a unique prefix for your tagged content. You can replace `"EvaluationTag"` with your specific tag name.
- Then, it uses `ClearAll` or `Remove` with a pattern to clear or remove all symbols with names that start with `taggedContext`.